# Error on flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am facing an issue while running the app. Before it used to work, all of sudden it is started showing the compilation error.

Flutter version: 3.8.1

Dart version: 3.8.1

**Compiler Message:**

```
/C:/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar- 
1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:273:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has more required 
arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.

void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
   ^
/C:/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.5- 
stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:40:8: Context: This is the overridden 
method ('install').

void install() {
   ^
/C:/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar- 
1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
super.install(insertionPoint);
```

**strong text**

Comment: There is a conversation about this happening here : https://github.com/AndreHaueisen/flushbar/issues/113
Unfortunately none of the suggested fixes there are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by the `flushbar` plugin. You can either downgrade to a previously working version or upgrade to 1.9.1 which [reportedly fixes the issue](https://github.com/AndreHaueisen/flushbar/issues/113#issuecomment-612635655).